# Getting started with Visual Studio 2010 Extensibility - 3 questions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx

1.) How differs "Visual Studio Package" project from the "VSIX" project?

2.) Where I can find some beginners guides?

3.) Where I can find a overview of the extensibility model or extension points of Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you explain what type of extension you want to write?  It may change my answers here.

1. Both projects produce a VSIX.  the VSIX project just produces an empty one, whereas the package project sets you up with a Managed Package Framework package.  Here are [some walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138565.aspx) for packages.
2. You can try the main page for [extending visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend).  If you give more information about what you want to build, I can point you at more specific sources.
3. Depends on what you are trying to do.  There are guides on [the Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx), which has sections on language services, editors (adding new editor factories or extending the built-in editor), extending the debugger, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more about the VSPackage? As I know, Visual Studio 2010 uses MEF(Managed Extensibility Framework). Why does not the SDK support a service the the command bars? Isn't that the old way(COM, ect.)?

Comment: Some parts of VS2010 use MEF (the editor, primarily, and also the project system in parts).  The extensibility services related to the shell (editor factory, tool windows, commands, tools->options pages) and debugger (debugger integration for a language), along with a few others, have the same extensibility story they had in VS2008.

Comment: MPF == Managed Package Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166554.aspx