# What is the difference between Visual Studio Package and VSIX Project types?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sdk

In VS2010 SDK extensibility what is the difference between "Visual Studio Package" project type & "VSIX Project" type ? Both of them are producing VSIX files for publishing the templates.

Answer (score 5):

This has actually been answered as part of a suite of questions asked here:

[Getting started with Visual Studio 2010 Extensibility - 3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4627829/1444911)

> Both projects produce a VSIX. the VSIX project just produces an empty
>   one, whereas the package project sets you up with a Managed Package
>   Framework package. Here are some walkthroughs for packages.

As this is specific to this particular problem, I think its worthwhile keeping it as a separate Q/A rather than closing the question.